# How do I make a link on my website for many users but pointing to the same template page?

Tags: php, application-design

I'm making a website where people write anonymous messages to users.
Each user should have a "public" page where there's only his/her image, name and a text area so that everyone can write to them.

While registering, each user will have a link to share with people so they go there and write their secret messages, example: `mywebsite.com/john.php`, and for another user `mywebsite.com/alice.php`.

The question is that I want to make only one page as a template and when we request John's page, his image and name will be queried from the database. So how can I do this with every user assigned a different link? I don't want people to request — for example — `myWebsite.com/template.php?user=John`, I want them to request `mywebsite.com/john`.

Is that even possible? Any suggestion will be awesome since I'm a beginner and confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache for server, you may use `mod_rewrite` to [route all request](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04) to the same `index.php` file, or any URL pattern you like. Its pretty powerful.

For example, this config will redirect all "file / directory not found" case to the `index.php` file. You need to either put it to your Apache `VirtualHost` config directive or .htaccess (if you have `AllowOverride all` set).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

You may do similar tricks on [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) with the [`try_files`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#check-if-file-exists) setting.

You'd then have to do your own URL detect on your `index.php` to correctly serve content for that specific URL. You may try libraries like [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute).

Comment: Thanks a lot and I'll read about all this asap.. but before that, a quick question .. after doing this mod, does this appear in the url of the requested page, for example if we requested website.com/alice and it successfully redirected us to the template page, will the link look like website.com/template "after redirection"

Comment: The nginx `try_files` is absolutely aliasing instead of redirection, which is what you're talking about. The Apache `mod_rewrite` module is considerablely more powerful so it can do both redirection and aliasing. The rewrite rules I provided above as an example is aliasing.

Comment: I watched a tutorial about mod rewrite "in htaccess" .. ideas started coming to mind.. thanks a lot for ur guidance..

Answer (score 0):

a few ways of doing it

1. Rewrite Mod (as Koala's answer)
2. Frameworks to customize your own route (e.g. [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x))
3. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`